# Populating Listview from Sqlite for Filtering

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-arrayadapter

I am trying and failing to implement a filtering list with edit text in my application. At the moment I can populate the list with a predefined string of elements but when I create an array from cursor results of an SQL query I cannot get this array to populate the list.

When I attempt to run the activity I am faced with a null pointer exception, I know what null pointers are and how they work but for the life of me I cannot figure out this one.

**Populating the Arrays**

```
        // Predefined List element
    String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
            "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
            "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};



    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    //calling to database to get elements
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllRecipes();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("recipe_name"));
        array.add(name);
    }

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.recipeName, array);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**DB Query**

```
    //get all recipes
public Cursor getAllRecipes()
{
    return db.query(RECIPE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_RECIPE_NAME}, null, null,null, null, null);
}
```

**Error**

```
01-31 19:01:01.876 6305-6305/com.example.rory.prototypev2 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
01-31 19:01:01.876 6305-6305/com.example.rory.prototypev2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rory.prototypev2.DBMain.getAllRecipes(DBMain.java:242)
01-31 19:01:01.876 6305-6305/com.example.rory.prototypev2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rory.prototypev2.dynamicSearch.onCreate(dynamicSearch.java:51)
```

**Init of DB**

```
DBMain db = new DBMain(this);
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you initialize the `db` variable for `db.query`?

Comment: You could alternatively use a CursorAdapter

Comment: I  just updated it there, I was going to try use a custom adapter but i couldnt get the `.getFilter()` function to work with it

Comment: You added the wrong `db` variable. That's the class that has the getAllRecipes method. There is also a `db` variable in DBMain that is null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null pointers that always got me where the id's of elements in the XML so maybe check there as well. But for a simple cursor adapter for a list view try the below

**Cursor with results form DB query**

```
        db.open();

    db.getAllRecipes();

    Cursor cursor2 = db.getAllRecipes();

    //String[] columns = column names from database
    String[] columns = new String[] {column names from database};

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.'id for XML element'};

    final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.'layout for individual list item', cursor2, columns, to, 0);
    //myCursorAdapter.getFilter().filter();
    lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

//updating list view
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            myCursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your `db` is null when you are calling `getAllRecipes()` .

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you declare `db`. I would expect to see something like this:

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this); 
//^^I've guessed the name "Database Helper", and that it takes a Context argument^^
db.getAllRecipes();
```

Also, if `getAllRecipes()` is a method inside a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, then you probably want to write:

```
public Cursor getAllRecipes() {
    return this.getReadableDatabase().query(RECIPE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_RECIPE_NAME}, null, null,null, null, null);
}
```

instead.